# How does DateTime.Now.Ticks exactly work?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In my application I generate files at random opportunities. To ensure a unique naming, I tried to use the nano seconds since 1.1.1970:

```
long time = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
String fileName = Convert.ToString(time);
Console.WriteLine(fileName);
```

Now I observed something weird. Why is the output like that? I mean why are the last 4 numbers always the same? I can use this as a filename, that is not the problem, but I'm just wondering about it.

```
634292263478068039
634292263512888039
634292263541368039
634292263603448039
634292263680078039
```

Comment: `Ticks` are not the nano seconds since `1.1.1970`, you're probably confused with the JavaScript `getTime()` method. Taken from the official msdn website: *The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

Comment: To be precise a tick is not a nanosecond, a tick is intended to represent 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The resolution of [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) depends on your system timer (~10ms on a current Windows OS)...so it's giving the same ending value there (it doesn't count any more finite than that).

Comment: But why is it exactly 39 at the end and not an even number?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - When it started counting, that was the value, after that you're only seeing ~10ms increments *from the initial value*, hope I'm conveying that clearly...let me know if not.

Comment: Yes it is more or less clear, I just wonder why the value is always 39 even if i restart the computer or the application.

Comment: @Roflcoptr - That I can't say, it's all down to your system clock hardware ultimately...if you try it on another machine with a different motherboard you'll likely see a different result.

Comment: Because of the System Timer. This does not have anything to do with when the computer was turned on or when the program was started. It's dependent on the machine. Odds are that if you run it on another machine you would get a different ending number.

Comment: To be noted that its not always a 10 ms interval. launch chrome with flash and it will get down to 1ms. because kernel ticks can be set between 1 and 15 ms through multimedia API.

Answer (score 25):

Not really an answer to your question as asked, but thought I'd chip in about your general objective.

There already is a method to generate random file names in .NET.

See [System.Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) and [GetRandomFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx).

Alternatively, it is a common practice to use a GUID to name random files.

Comment: Thanks, but this method return crypthographic names, so i prefer just some numbers which also have the advantage that it is easy to compare to each other

Comment: `GetRandomFileName`: I never even knew that existed!

Comment: @StevenRands I don't believe that `GetRandomFileName` returns an **unused** filename though, whereas `GetTempFileName` does.

Comment: @Dai That's correct. `GetTimeFileName` will actually create a (0-byte) file on disk, whereas `GetRandomFileName` is just returning a string that you *could* use as a filename, so collisions are possible (albeit unlikely).

Answer (score 16):

You can get the milliseconds since 1/1/1970 using such code:

```
private static DateTime JanFirst1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
public static long getTime()
{
    return (long)((DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - JanFirst1970).TotalMilliseconds + 0.5);
}
```

Comment: o_O --> what's the +0.5 at the end for ?!

Comment: @Noctis rough rounding technique I got used to when typecasting to integer/long. 1.9 would be converted to 2 this way, and not to 1.

Comment: Interesting ... probably not that important when you're casting a datetime to milliseconds, but I'll keep it mind for the future ... :)

Comment: Does this accommodate midnight?

Comment: @DanGifford yes, the DateTime constructor overload defaults the Hours, Minutes, and Seconds all to 0

Comment: Use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`, since the latter is a roundabout way to get to the former. Doing it this way is more efficient :)

Comment: How does this answers the question?

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier by offering a workaround that generates unique numbers, without repeating last four digits. Also, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554136/how-does-datetime-now-ticks-exactly-work#comment4993102_4554136) please.

Comment: @ShadowWizard From his words : `I can use this as a filename, that is not the problem, but I'm just wondering about it.`, plus this solution doesn't generate more unique numbers than his solution because of the resolution of `DateTime.Now` (see @Nick Craver solution)

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier sorry, don't have much more to say. At least 12 users found this helpful (by upvoting) so it means the answer has value. I won't remove it.

Answer (score 5):

to convert the current datetime to file name to save files you can use

```
DateTime.Now.ToFileTime();
```

this should resolve your objective

Comment: Not my downvote...but this would have the same time resolution issues as `.Ticks`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

I would also look at this answer: [Is there a high resolution (microsecond, nanosecond) DateTime object available for the CLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358860/is-there-a-high-resolution-microsecond-nanosecond-datetime-object-available-f).

About half-way down is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359304/) by "Robert P" with some extension functions I found useful.