# C# 6 digits milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime

Quick question: how can I get 6 digits milliseconds? the limit is 3.
other alternatives? suggestions?

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 08, 08, 08, 10, 10, 100)
```

Comment: Milliseconds are thousands of a second. There are only 3 digits for that (0-999)

Comment: You probably are trying to set microseconds or nanoseconds?  If so have a look at this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358860/is-there-a-high-resolution-microsecond-nanosecond-datetime-object-available-f

Answer (score 7):

[Milli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milli-) is a prefix meaning *thousands*. Thus, one millisecond is one thousandth of a second. What you probably mean by "6 digit milliseconds" is *[microseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)*.

Luckily, DateTime internally stores [Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) with a resolution of 100 nanoseconds (= 0.1 microseconds), so you can just read the Tick property and divide it by 10 to get the total number of microseconds that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001.