# Datetime accuracy when getting data from DB2 using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, db2

I have an IBM DB2 database, and I need to get values from one column that is primary key and it is TIMESTAMP.
That primary key is in this format: dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.ffffff

I need to get it with full accuracy.
But, when I use Entity framework for getting the data last 3 numbers of are lost.

I get this format: dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff.
Is there an easy way to solve this problem and get precise data, like telling Entity framework in some way that I am expecting datatime in this specific format?

Comment: Is it stored with the milliseconds in the database? If not, you could store it as a string, and then parse it back to a full format using DateTime.ParseExact(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have more than 3 digits for the miliseconds. They can only be from 0-999.

Comment: @PedroG.Dias Hi Pedro, thanks for answering. In DB2 value is stored in correct format. It is a timestamp, the problem occurs when Entity framework gets it from there. I think that it's the one that cut last 3 numbers...

Comment: Maybe a workaround is to map the datetime field to a string, and then using ParseExact, thus bypassing the DateTime conversion done by EF - might not be a good solution in terms of performance though, maybe someone knows a better way?

Comment: No. The problem is, that the DB2 TIMESTAMP appears to have an accuracy of microseconds, but DateTime can only handle miliseconds. He can not hold the full accuracy of TIMESTAMP in a DateTime no matter how he parses it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timestamp data from DB2 is not accurate when using EntityFramework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298510/timestamp-data-from-db2-is-not-accurate-when-using-entityframework)

Comment: Side note:  Dates/times/timestamps have no format.  When output _as a string_ it will be formatted at that time.  The particular format chosen depends on culture, and potentially session settings.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value as both a DateTime and text, parse the microseconds and add them to the DateTime using code from here:

[Is there a high resolution (microsecond, nanosecond) DateTime object available for the CLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358860/is-there-a-high-resolution-microsecond-nanosecond-datetime-object-available-f)