# Datetime.Now evaluation in function call

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm currently working on a piece of code where i need to name a folder based on the current week of year (according to the ISO8601 standard).

The folder is going to be named: "y[year]w[week-of-year]". So for instance the folders name could be "y2016w42" this week.

I currently do the following:

```
DateTime n = DateTime.Now;
string folderName = "y" + n.Year + "w" + DataHelper.WeekOfYearISO8601(n);
```

Where i first assign the current time to a variable n, before using it to generate the folder name.

Now i would actually rather just do the following:

```
string folderName = "y" + DateTime.Now.Year + "w" + DataHelper.WeekOfYearISO8601(DateTime.Now);
```

Is DateTime.Now evaluated to an actual time once or twice? Does the compiler re-use it from the first evaluation, or do i actually get two different timestamps in this scenario?

I'm sure this code works 99.9999% of the time but what happens if this code were to run on New Years Evening at midnight? (lets just ignore the fact that the week of year does not neccesarily change on NYE according to the ISO8601 standard, and pretend they coincide this year).

If DateTime.Now is evaluated twice, i can imagine a scenario where one of the DateTimes are still in week 52 2016, and the other one is in week 1 2017. This could spell trouble as the folder then might be named "2017_52" or "2016_1", both of which are wrong - the correct would be either "2017_1" or "2016_52".

I'm sure the first snippet of code i provided is okay, but will the second snippet also work in all scenarios?

Comment: Why do you prefer the second version? (imho the first version is more readable and therefore easier to understand)

Comment: `string folderName = "y%sw%s" % (n.Year, DataHelper.WeekOfYearISO8601(n))` would be my preferred way: string concatenation is slow, as strings are immutable in Python. Filling a format string is faster.

Comment: @dexter: I think "DateTime.Now" is as undestandable as "n" and therefore the extra variable seems unnecessary, especially since i find myself doing this with DateTime quite often.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: Question is C#, but yes you are right, String.Format would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime.Now is reevaluated each time it is called, to a resolution of approx 10ms (there's a good discussion here of how accurate it is: [How does DateTime.Now.Ticks exactly work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554136/how-does-datetime-now-tick-exactly-work))

You can see this very easily (live version here: http://rextester.com/XJVEJ16515):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks);

var currVal = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    if (currVal != DateTime.Now.Ticks) {
        Console.WriteLine(currVal);
        currVal = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
> 636128255483021039 
> 636128255483177570
> 636128255483333827
> 636128255483489977 
> 636128255483646493 
> 636128255483802799
> 636128255483959218 
> 636128255484115758 
> 636128255484271805
> 636128255484428165
```

In this case, it's not actually splitting out a new value every millisecond

Cache the value and use it like you have in your original code; it's safer, but also easier to read!

Comment: Yeah, even writing to console _should_ take a little bit time also.

Answer (score 3):

> Is DateTime.Now evaluated to an actual time once or twice?

Since you called `DateTime.Now` twice, it is evaluated twice.

> I'm sure this code works 99.9999% of the time but what happens if this
>   code were to run on New Years Evening at midnight?

Exactly. Since this expression evaluated twice, they *probably* generate different results (assuming the clock *does* [`Tick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks) between the two property calls).

Use the first one, Luke.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `DateTime.Now` is evaluated each time it is called. There could be some optimizations I am not aware of, but you should take it as a fact just to be safe.

what you should do to stay safe in those 0.0001% of the times (probably much less, if at all) is to keep `DateTime.Now` in a variable, I really don't see a big advantage in your preferred option.

If it is possible, you can make sure it never runs on midnight, and that would also solve your problem..

Answer (score 1):

Saving the current DateTime in a variable is your best bet. If you call DateTime.Now twice, you will get different times.